# Повторяющийся символы в строке в языке Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, строки, циклы

Строка вводится с клавиатуры, удалить повторяющиеся символы.

Например:

```
allohaa
```

в результате получим

```
aloh
```

Мой код:

```py
str_1 = input("Введите строку:") 
count = 0 
symb = '' 
for el in str_1: 
    if str_1.count(el) > count: 
        count = str_1.count(el) 
        symb = el 
        print(el.replace(el, ''))
```

Comment: Что вы уже пробовали сделать и в чём у вас проблема? Задачка довольно простая, решается "в лоб" перебором символов строки в цикле, плюс один символ в промежуточной переменной хранится. Ну либо чуть хитрее через `zip` со сдвигом строки.

Comment: str_1 = input("Введите строку:")

count = 0
symb = ''

for el in str_1:
    if str_1.count(el) > count:
        count = str_1.count(el)
        symb = el
print(el.replace(el, ''))

Comment: Сейчас у меня что то такое)

Comment: Добавил ваш код в вопрос. Но не уверен про отступы. Не пишите код в комментариях, он там не форматируется нормально. В общем, это неправильный путь, просто попробуйте запоминать предыдущий символ и сравнивать с ним текущий. Потом либо печатайте символ либо не печатайте. Либо копите символы в строке или списке и выводите потом. Заменой строки лучше не пользоваться кроме случаев, когда вам надо какой-то символ совсем из строки удалить, у вас не тот случай.

Answer (score 1):

Просто используем `groupby`:

```py
# https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby
from itertools import groupby
s = "allohaa"
res = ''.join(k for k, g in groupby(s))
print(res) # aloha
```